# Как программно определить, размыто ли изображение?

Tags: android

Доброго времени суток.  
Как программно определить, размыто ли фото?
Нужно определить, размыто ли фото, и если да, то не дать отправить его на сервер. Возможно, есть какие-то библиотеки или готовые решения?   
Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Highpass фильтр оставляет в изображении "высокочастотные", мелкие детали. Если таковых нет — изображение, вероятно, не в фокусе. Грубо говоря, нужно применить этот фильтр и оценить, как много пикселей отличаются по яркости от нейтрального серого, чтобы судить о количестве четких деталей в картинке.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Для этого применяется т.н. [алгоритм преобразования Фурье](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%A4%D1%83%D1%80%D1%8C%D0%B5) - для обыденного понимания достаточно рассматривать это как разложение сигнала на набор синусоид (сейчас закидают тапочками математики...).

Изображение надо рассматривать как двумерный сигнал и, соответственно, разложить его в двумерный ряд Фурье, полученный сигнал проанализировать. В реальных вычислениях применяется дискретное преобразование Фурье - принято обозначать это как `FFT` - Fast Fourier Transformation.

Если в сигнале слишком мало высокочастотных компонент, значит изображение размыто.

Что такое слишком много или слишком мало - устанавливайте сами.

Для упрощения анализа опять-таки принято полученный сигнал (а по сути новый битмап) проинтегрировать (например, Лапласом) и получить одномерный вектор, который-таки более удобен для анализа.

В общем, как-то так. Гуглите по ключевому слову FFT+Java - авось повезет.

Comment: спасибо буду пробовать )